# Questions Related To Forking a Process

Tags: c++, c, sockets, fork

I am making a server and I use fork() for creating child processes but I have doubts about that. Here are some:

1. Why do you need to close main socket in a child process and new connection accepted socket in the parent process? (after accepting a new connection) I thought that sockets are only integers with some id which are used to access opened sockets in some system-wide object which is only acceptable through system functions calls. In that case fork would only copy the integer but would have no affect on socket opened.
2. I have checked and found out that if I fork a process inside a class method, all members are copied. Well, I have found out it is copy-on-edit so does it mean that my server class will be copied in each child that uses a non-constant function? How do I make some memory shared between all such processes (like a list of tasks and each child puts something into it while the parent is reading stuff from it)? I guess fork is not the right function for that. What is the best way?

P.S. I am pretty sure I know the answer to the second question, which is clone(), but just wanted to make sure that's the right function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Sockets in Unix are File descriptors and they are indeed integers, as seen by the user, but they really are indexes into a table that the kernel maintains per process. In this table each *file descriptor* (FD) refers to an *open file description* (OFD) that are system-wide objects maintained in kernel. When you do `fork()` the opened *file descriptors* are duplicated and both child's and parent's point to the same OFD. Having two FDs that refer to the same OFD is not usually a problem, but particularly with sockets they can have subtle problems, as the connection is closed only when you close *all* the FDs that refer to it.
2. You should really consider using threads (do not close the sockets if you use threads!). `clone` is a linux system call and is not intended to be used directly. Your alternative is to use shared memory but it is kind of more complex.

Comment: This was VERY informative. And it did really explain the sockets thing well. Now it's very clear. Actually I have some experience with multi-threading. I have worked with pthreads but fork seemed nice because you don't need another function to do the thing. But... I will probably use pthreads now ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. The `int` is a handle, but the socket itself is still associated with the process. The child closes the listening socket mainly for safety reasons (it doesn't need it, and if the child ever spawns another process, that process would inherit the socket as well); the server process closes the new connection's socket because otherwise the connection would remain open until the server process exits (the socket exists as long as at least one process still has a handle to it).
2. You either want multithreading or a proper shared memory approach. This is where the fun begins.

Shared memory between independent processes comes with interesting problems, but also provides otherwise impossible capabilities (for example, you can restart the master server process and leave the processes serving open connections running, which is difficult to get right as two different versions of the service then have to talk to each other, but allows seamless upgrades without disconnecting clients or interrupting service).

Sharing memory between threads is relatively easy, but threads share the same set of file descriptors, so you do not win much here.

Last, there is a third alternative: an event loop watching multiple sockets, giving attention to each only if something is actually happening. Look at the documentation for the `select` and `poll` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Forking duplicates file descriptors, so you have to close the duplicate.

Forking also effectively copies all memory (though in practice it's copy-on-write, so it's not very expensive). You make a new *process* which is entirely separate from the parent process, unless you explicitly set up some shared memory.

Maybe you intended to spawn a new *thread* rather than forking a new *process*?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to look through [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201433079) as a reference on fork().

1. Yes you do need to close the socket bound to listen in the child and accepted socket in the parent.  The integers aka file handles point to real structures [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755429/forking-with-a-listening-socket) so unless you want the kernel to dump a new connection on a child or parent being able to send the data to the connected client you might want to prevent this outright.
2. To share data for between the processes the best way is shared memory.  The book I referred you to will have quite a bit of information regarding that too.  In general if you need to share memory without shared memory then you might want to look at threads.

P.S.  I'm not sure which clone() method you are referring to.  Object copying is done via copy constructors.